# What is needed for a minor to cross the US/Canada border via bus

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, us-citizens, minors

I'm going to be traveling from the U.S. to Canada by myself (age 16) without any adults. I'm planning on taking a bus, and I was wondering what all I'll need. I've looked up online plenty, and the requirements are different per-site which isn't helpful. I'm currently not emancipated, and I do not have a passport.

Comment: Step 1 - Get a passport.

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: @CMaster U.S. citizenship

Comment: @Tom If that's the only way I shall

Comment: Passports are required to re-enter the USA and also required for minors to enter Canada - http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/minors.asp

Comment: @Tom US citizens can enter Canada with any proof of citizenship, such as a US birth certificate.  Minors under sixteen can enter the US from Canada, Mexico, or the Caribbean without a passport, although that doesn't help the OP.

Comment: Have you asked the bus company?  They probably won't let you board if your documents don't meet their requirements, which will be at least as strict as the government requirements.  For example, Canada will let you in with only a US birth certificate, but the bus company might not let you board with only a US birth certificate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canada will admit US citizens with any proof of citizenship, such as a US    birth certificate, along with photo ID.  The two can be the same document, if course, if you are using, for example, a passport.  Source: http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html#_s2a

The US, on the other hand, requires more secure documentation.  These requirements are codified as the [Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative (WHTI)](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative).  The WHTI has less stringent requirements for those under 16, which doesn't help you.

You should therefore most likely get a US passport or passport card.  The latter makes sense mostly if you are planning not to travel to other countries in the next ten years, or if you plan to travel by land or sea, relatively frequently, to Canada, Mexico, or the Caribbean.

If you live in one of the states that offer them, you also have the option of getting an enhanced driver's license or state DMV non-driver identification card.

Finally, you should also ask the bus company about their requirements, since these could be more restrictive.

Comment: Your link starts by saying adults and chikdren traveling with.  My link in the comments specifically covers the OPs situation, that of a minor traveling by themselves.

Comment: @Tom your link starts by saying that a minor must follow the rules for any other visitor .  For a US citizen minor, then, a case not otherwise explicitly covered on that page, a passport is not required.

Comment: So I could get there, but I'd be stuck lol. I'll probably talk with my parents and see if I can go there with my certificate/ID (If it meets the busing standards) and get a passport mailed over (since processing takes time)

Comment: @Jake you won't be stuck. The US can't deny entrance to its own citizens. You might be a pain in the ass. If you got into Canada with proof of citizenship, you'll eventually get back into the US. I don't recommend it though.

Comment: @PressTilty you are absolutely right that the US must admit all US citizens, but the bus company is not obliged to transport US citizens whose documents fail to meet WHTI requirements.

Comment: @phoog that's true. However, the last time I took a bus across the border the driver didn't even ask about my travel documents.

Comment: At least not that I can recall and it was only last month.

Comment: @phoog - The minor page does not list any exceptions even for US citizens, your link has no references applying to minors traveling alone and your link also recommends ALL travelers have passports. I am amazed and saddened by the advice given here encouraging people to push the limits of bypassing the regulations.  A passport is a basic need for ALL international travel and to advise a 16 year not to bother is irresponsible and (I won't resort to name calling).

Comment: @Tom Did you read the answer? I did not advise anyone not to bother ("you should therefore most likely..."). The page you linked to contradicts itself; you and I obviously disagree about what that means. I am quite certain that "follow the rules for any other visitor" is the more important phrase, meaning that a US citizen can show separate proof of identity and citizenship in lieu of a passport. The main purpose of the document list is clearly to show *additional* documents that a minor must show when traveling alone, not to say that US citizens who are under 18 uniquely must show a passport.

Comment: @phoog - My comment about advice was aimed at many posts on this forum (not just yours), where members have argued at great lengths to prove you don't need a passport. As a travel professional I have had to deal with and assist the weenies who thought they could buck the system and then find themselves in hot water somewhere else.  The bottom line - having a passport to travel outside the USA IS the NUMBER ONE RULE.

Comment: @Tom in a forum full of geeks who delight in exploring every possible exception, qualification, and refinement of every rule, what do you expect? The fact is that Canada *recommends* and does not *require* US citizens to have passports or WHTI-compliant documents to enter. Of course, real-world situations where that fact is useful will be few and far between, given that the US *does* ostensibly require WHTI-compliant documents for US citizens to get back in. That doesn't stop discussion of such situations, especially when the question is about what is "needed," not "recommended."

Comment: @phoog - This forum is also full of people wanting accurate information to make their travels more enjoyable, not bad advice that leads to a few hours answering questions in a back room trying to prove you have the right to re-enter the US without a passport.